# WebSphere CI deployment plugins options (Bamboo)

Tags: plugins, deployment, continuous-integration, websphere, bamboo

I am very fresh in WebSphere application server and I am setting a CI deployment on it.

So far, I have achieved this target by using a Jython script executed by wsadmin.
This actually seems to be a good approach, but, I was wondering if there are any other plugins that can simplify the maintainability of this script.

The CI server I am working on is Bamboo (Atlassian), and all the choices I have been able to find are a Apache Maven plugin and some WebSphere plugin from Atlassian market place.

Would you give me any recommendations or best practices? Can you recommend any other plugin implementable on Bamboo?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Enrique, did you find the solution? If so, please, can you answer here?